# PHP - Best practice to concatenate multiple array values

Tags: php, arrays

I want to concatenate some string in this way:

```
"string A"
"string B"

my expectation result : "string A \n string B"
```

And Here my initial array look like this :

```
array:1 [
  0 => array:2 [
    "foo" => array:1 [
      0 => "string A"
    ]
    "bar" => array:1 [
      0 => "string B"
    ]
  ]
]
```

What is the best practice for doing this?

Comment: There is no best practice for something mundane like this, once you know how to manipulate arrays, it just comes with practice to do it in less code.

Comment: Is there any built-in function in php or recursive way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems as though you could use a fairly generic array-flattening function for this:

```
function get_flattened_values($arr, $glue = "\n"){
  $result = array();

  // For each array item in this level of the array
  foreach($arr as $item){

    // If it's the element is an array, recurs and push the result
    if(is_array($item)){
      $result[] = get_flattened_values($item);

    // Else, if it's a string, just push the string
    } else if (is_string($item)){
      $result[] = $item;
    }
  }

  // Join our result together
  return implode($glue, $result);

}
```

**Example at [eval.in](https://eval.in/830057)**

Comment: nice , but there is a problem , my final result is look this : """string A string B """ what is your suggestion for convert to "string A string B"

Comment: So you have quotes in your input array?

Answer (score 0):

There's two arrays nested in OP's example. So you'll need two loops if you don't pop off the top.

```
$array1 = array("foo" => "something");
$array2 = array("bar" => "somethingelse");
$result = array_merge($array1, $array2);

//your array here:
$mytest = (array($result));
foreach ($mytest as $key => $value)
{
  foreach($value as $innerItem => $innerValue){
      $str .= ($innerValue);
  }
}

echo($str);
```